# How to encode string correctly in Java/Kotlin that has been decoded in Python

Tags: python, java, android, json, kotlin

I am trying to upload and download `.so` file while it will be saved in MongoDB on the server, for the server I am using Python/flask and the client is android (Kotlin or Java)

**Server side:**

I am trying to upload a `.so` compiled file using Python/Flask and save it in MongoDB:

```py
from bson.binary import Binary
...
socket = request.files['socket'] # .so file
binary = socket.read()
encoded = Binary(binary)

# update it in MongoDB using Pymongo
...
```

And when I want to return it I am doing that using:

```py
# Retrieve socket string from MongoDB
...

final_string = socket.decode('unicode_escape')

# Send it back in a JSON response
...
```

**Client side:**
On the client side (android Java or Kotlin):

```kotlin
// Get the decoded socket string from the retrieved JSON object (OkHttp)
val socketFile= File(filesDir, "socket.so")
if (socketFile.exists()){
         socketFile.delete()
}
socketFile.createNewFile()
socketFile.writeBytes(data.toByteArray()) // data is the socked decoded string from the json respose
```

For all those steps there is no errors, but when I run the received `.so` file it crashes with these errors:

```
E/fdsan: attempted to close file descriptor 107, expected to be unowned, actually owned by unique_fd 0x724c5d22c4
A/libc: Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0x71cf0e39dc in tid 18912 (Thread-9), pid 18672 (me.jagar.rog)
E/Fence: sync_file_info returned NULL for fd 107
E/Fence: sync_file_info returned NULL for fd 107
E/com.example.package: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x800000
```

I thought it could be an encoding/decoding problem but I am not sure how to adjust it to make it work

### Edit 1:

I didn't use `base64` encoding in the server or the client, and here is partially (it is so long) how the data string received looks like in the JSON file:

```json
{
"data": "ELF          ·    %      @       °          @ 8     @         @       @       @       ø      ø                   8      8      8                                                                                  x      x     x     8      à                   ¨      ¨     ¨                                P      P      P      ¼       ¼              Påtd   `      `      `      T       T              Qåtd                                                  Råtd   x      x     x                        /system/bin/linker64             Android    r20                                                             5594570                                                                  GNU » À9:o%BÏ´ihÔ½°    a   f   3       )       F   *   5       
       !   K   P   N   A   4       O   ^   L   I                           $   R       M   G   e                       #   V   c          0   Z                 '   2          (          D              ?          W   ,                           d       >   ]   [                       &       1   8   Y       "   \   +   9   E         H                               .       6   @       :           =                         b      J   C           X           B               <               7       `       a   Q                   _                          /               S       -                                                           U   ;                                                      T   %                  
                  %   $            " p   ,   `h à%¥@)r V ! @  $G ¥TJY"  $               *   ,   -   .   0   1   4   9   :   <   @   G   H   J       L   O   P   R   S   U   V           X   Z   ^       a       b   d       Ð¦}aü8-Òj¶ /Bù
A(¸füCaC¥°£ôf ......."
}
```

The file size (socket.so) is about 39KB and it can be reproduced using a simple C++ compiled file

Comment: You haven't shown how you're populating the `data` variable, nor do we know how the binary data is encoded in the JSON. (It should be base64-encoded, but you haven't shown us anything about that.) It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] including the JSON.

Comment: @JonSkeet please find the edit 1

Comment: There's still no sign of the JSON. Fundamentally, JSON is a text-based format - if you're not using something like base64, you should *expect* there to be problems with arbitrary binary data. I strongly suggest you start using base64 to encode the binary data...

Comment: thank you @JonSkeet, I explained more in the edit 1, the data is just like compiled stuff and even changes when I copy/paste it, I will try with base64 encoding instead as you suggested

Comment: "the data is just like compiled stuff" - yes, as I say, arbitrary binary data. **Not text data** - which is why you need to encode it.